# Ubuntu 17.10 does not boot with Windows Bootloader

Tags: dual-boot, 17.10, bootloader

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and installed Windows 7 to another partition. The installation went well and Windows booted regulary. I then configurated the Windows bootloader with EasyBCD, adding Ubuntu to it and to boot it on default.

Till then, everything was fine, but when the computer attemps to boot Ubuntu, it gets stuck in a blank screen with blinking cursor.

As the EasyBCD is in German, I tried my best to translate the current configuration entry precisely:

```
There are existing 2 entries in the bootloader.
Default: Ubuntu 17.10
time till start: 15 Seconds
StartDrive: C:\

Entry #1
Name: Ubuntu 17.10
BCD ID: {default}
Device: boot
Bootloader Path: \NST\nst_linux.mbr

Entry #2
Name: Windows 7
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe
```

Comment: Would Grub, Ubuntu's default boot loader, be a suitable replacement?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu partition needs a partition boot loader (PBR) and not a master bootloader (MBR) which in this case belongs to Windows.

Comment: Alright, but how do i install it, or is it already, but it isn't assigned yet?